# Need to create a movie size 720:-1 with a delay in it's 2 first seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use the scale filter and also add a delay in the first X seconds of a movie.

I tried to use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -filter_complex 
"scale=720:-1[scale];tpad=start_duration=2;adelay=2s|2s" -map "[scale]" 
scaled720.mp4
```

What I want is a video with a specific size (720:-1 - aspect ratio) that will also have a delay in the first 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=720:-1,tpad=start_duration=2[v];[0:a]adelay=2s:all=true[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" scaled720.mp4
```

The filter inputs and outputs should be properly labeled to avoid ambiguity. See [filtering introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) and [filtergraph syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. great answer.